# Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2008: Mix of data sources in Report and subreport?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, report, crystal-reports-2008

I have a winforms applications that does some reporting using Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2008.
I'm facing the situation where I have to add new data to one of those reports, that uses odbc as its data source.
Since the new data I have to add is quite complex to process with CR Table Designer (odbc) I'm thinking on doing all the processing by code and pass the output using a DataSet. Also, I don't want to migrate the whole report to DataSets as data source.
I know I can't use Odbc and DataSet on the same report but can I do this on a subreport?.
I mean, keep the main report as odbc and add a subreport with DataSets as its source?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is that yes, you can. We provide independent datasets to subreports all of the time using the report's `Database.Tables([SubReportTableName]).SetDataSource()` method.

Comment: What do you mean by SubReportTableName?. I have tryed doing that using  subreport's name and it throws an exception:
Index is not valid (HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))

I was able to set subreports datasource using report's `SubReports[SubReportName].SetDataSource()` method.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained better: we operate on the list of tables in the report, which includes both data from both the main report and the subreports. That code is in a loop on Report.Database.Tables and we know which subreport is associated with which table, hence the name of the variable. Your way (obviously) works as well.